# Como fazer um web crawler acessar páginas que precisam de autenticação?

Tags: web-crawler

Preciso desenvolver um web-crowler onde ele iria acessar uma pagina (na qual é necessario login e eu tenho tais credenciais) e o "robô" iria encontrar todos os links da pagina e listar em algum lugar, podendo ser um memo ou até mesmo um arquivo txt. Seria um processo semelhante ao plugin DownThemmAll do firefox.
A autenticação do site é simples, feita via https. Mas também tenho a opção de digitar captcha para acessar a pagina com os arquivos.

Comment: Essa pergunta está muito ampla, não creio que possa ser respondida na forma como está. Qualquer linguagem pode igualmente ser usada para implementar um crawler, e existem diversas bibliotecas prontas para auxiliar nesse processo. Quanto a acessar páginas que precisam de login, creio que é possível sim (supondo que você tem as credenciais de acesso), mas vai depender muito da forma como o site faz a autenticação e menutenção das sessões. Por favor edite sua pergunta colocando mais contexto, assim talvez possamos te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Olá @mgibsonbr , fiz uma edição, espero que tenha sido claro. Valeu.

Comment: Está melhor agora, eu responderia mas não creio que tenha conhecimento suficiente pra tal. Mas não entendi muito bem: quando você diz que se refere a "autenticação via https" você quer dizer [com certificados no lado cliente](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736680%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)? E esse captcha tem de ser usado sempre, ou há uma forma alternativa de autenticação?

Comment: Tenho 2 opções, uma seria o login para que eu possa acessar a pagina com as informações e a outra seria o captcha.
Exemplo, eu entro no site da receita federal com um CPF, se eu tenho as credenciais do site eu não preciso digitar o captcha para retornar as informações, mas se eu não tiver as credenciais é necessário. No meu caso eu tenho as credenciais.

Comment: Nesse caso, volta ao que falei no meu primeiro comentário: é necessário saber como o site autentica (provavelmente através de uma requisição POST) e como ele mantém a sessão (provavelmente através de um cookie). Não conheço muitas bibliotecas de crawling, mas provavelmente deve ter uma que dê suporte a esse tipo de coisa.

Comment: Esse programa possui algum requisito quanto à linguagem?

Comment: @MiguelAngelo não, quanto a linguagem não é problema.

Comment: O site mantém uma credencial em meu navegador e a seção expira em 30 minutos. Creio que deva manter cookies.

Comment: Qual a linguagem que será utilizada?

Comment: @GT8 Nenhuma ainda, estou pesquisando qual melhor se aplica a minhas necessidades, estou pensando em perl, py ou até mesmo pascal (que encontrei ótimas ferramentas).

Comment: Por que tanto downvote? Alguém poderia deixar um comentário, se acha que a pergunta precisa ser melhorada, por favor?

Comment: @mgibsonbr apesar de não ter dado o -1, eu acho que você mesmo disse o que estava errado em seu 1o comentário. (quase) qualquer linguagem poderia ser usada, cada site poderá ter um método diferente de fornecer dados de login, e "ser simples" não dá detalhes de como é feita realmente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu tenho alguns crawlers em PHP que acessam páginas que exigem credenciais. Depende de cada caso, já que cada um tem uma forma de autenticação. No meu caso, eu conheço as formas exigidas. Por exemplo, acesso um site em que a página de login deles contém o seguinte formulário:

```
<form class="onclick-submit card grid-3" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="https://painel2.oculto.net/conectorPainel.php" id="frmLogin" >
    <input class="hidden" type="text" name="email" id="txtUserName" value="meu@email.com" />
    <input class="hidden" type="password" name="senha" id="txtPassword" value="senha" />
    <input class="hidden" type="checkbox" name="permanecerlogado" tabindex="6" id="chkRemember" checked="checked" />
    <input class="hidden" type="hidden" value="login" name="acao" />
    ...
</form>
```

Neste caso, meu crawler em PHP faz uma autenticação no site antes de processar o conteúdo:

```
$curl = new cURL();
$curl->post('https://painel2.oculto.net/conectorPainel.php', 'email=meu@email.com&senha=senha&permanecerlogado=1&acao=login');
```

O site criará uma sessão para meus acessos subsequentes e o programa terá acesso privilegiado. Nem sequer verifico a resposta do site, já que as chances de falha de login são mínimas e se for negado por alguma outra falha (como falha na conexão, baixa no servidor, etc) o programa  interromperá a execução e tentará mais tarde.

A maioria dos sites requer, portanto, apenas 3 informações básicas:

- login
- senha
- URL

Mas com certeza isto não funciona para todos, já que alguns sites criam tokens para cada sessão (e.g.: icloud.com) ou algum algoritmo que dificulta a automação. Nestes casos, requer programação manual.